# How to use rate limit descriptors for local rate limiting in Envoy?

Tags: envoyproxy

I am trying to add [local rate limit filter](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.18.2/configuration/http/http_filters/local_rate_limit_filter) to [front-proxy](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/examples/front-proxy/front-envoy.yaml) example. The default token bucket works as expected, but local descriptor's token bucket doesn't.

Here is my `route_config` changes in [front-envoy.yaml](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/examples/front-proxy/front-envoy.yaml):

```yaml
route_config:
  name: local_route
  virtual_hosts:
  - name: backend
    domains:
    - "*"
    routes:
    - match:
        prefix: "/service/2"
      route:
        cluster: service2
    - match:
        prefix: "/service/1"
      route:
        cluster: service1
        rate_limits:
        - actions:
          # https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.18.2/api-v3/config/route/v3/route_components.proto#envoy-v3-api-msg-config-route-v3-ratelimit-action-requestheaders
          - request_headers:
            header_name: ":path"
            descriptor_key: path

      typed_per_filter_config:
        envoy.filters.http.local_ratelimit:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.local_ratelimit.v3.LocalRateLimit
          stat_prefix: http_local_rate_limiter

          # if there is no matching descriptor entries, the default token bucket is used
          token_bucket:
            max_tokens: 3
            tokens_per_fill: 3
            fill_interval: 60s

          filter_enabled:
            default_value:
              numerator: 100
              denominator: HUNDRED
          filter_enforced:
            default_value:
              numerator: 100
              denominator: HUNDRED
          descriptors:
          - entries:
            - key: path
              value: /service/1/foo/bar
            token_bucket:
              max_tokens: 1
              tokens_per_fill: 1
              fill_interval: 60s
```

I send 4 times `curl -v localhost:8080/service/1/foo/bar` and expect a 429 response on the second request, to match up a local descriptor.

But I got a 429 response only on the 4th attempt: there is no matching descriptor entries, the default token bucket is used.

Comment: Could be a typo . But seems like the indentation inside descriptor is incorrect . 

Ideally should be : 
          descriptors:
            - entries:
              - key: path
                value: /service/1/foo/bar
              token_bucket:
                max_tokens: 1
                tokens_per_fill: 1
                fill_interval: 60s

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an indentation issue :

```
          descriptors:
            - entries:
              - key: path
                value: /service/1/foo/bar
              token_bucket:
                max_tokens: 1
                tokens_per_fill: 1
                fill_interval: 60s
```